# how to find the angle between line and x-axies

Tags: geometry

I have an 2 GPS coordinate which represent an start and end point of line

so how to find the angle in image ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Gimp (or a similar graphics program), assigning coordinates is fairly easy. Gimp gives me (95,263) for the bottom point, and (211,78) for the top one. Then, referring back to the previous answer (the one by vladimirm), we get

$$
\Delta x = 116\quad \Delta y = 185\quad \text{angle} = \arctan \frac{185}{116} \approx 1.0107407\text{ radians} \approx 58^{\circ},  
$$
which seems about right.

Comment: no I wont some formula that work in my program because the A and B are location, which it moves :),,, but i got 1.0107407 with some try it seems I should convert it to radians , I will try  :)

Comment: did you are using Gimp for this image ?????

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it, and then opened it with Gimp. Gimp displays the mouse pointer coordinates in the status bar underneath the image.

Comment: I can't do such this trick but you give me a good idea, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign some coordinates to your points $A$ and $B$, and let the red line be parralel to the $x$ axis, then
$\Delta x = B_x - A_x$, $\Delta y = B_y - A_y$, Angle $= \arctan\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)   $

Comment: it gives me 0.35

Comment: In degrees that would be about 20, that seems wrong, What is your $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$?

Comment: it is an A location ( longitude and latitude ) , B Location ( longitude and latitude )
/Delta x = B longitude - B longitude 
/Delta y = B latitude - A latitude

Comment: You need to measure distances, the distance of point B to the red line (shortest distance), and the distance of the point B to a second line perpendicular to the red line going through A, those are your $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$, respectively.

Comment: it's too hard and need more formula but I will try :)

Comment: I have try this with this 2 coordinates 

`A = 54.899348, 33.051469
B = 54.982965, 33.145368`

Distance from B to red line = 10413.98 ==> /Delta y
Distance from B throw a to red line = 13014.53 ==> /Delta x

/Delta y / /Delta x = 0.80018102843514133818124818952356

arctan= 38.6661192

which it is not equal to real or near to it see this point in map 
by looking it equal [look here](https://www.google.jo/maps/dir/55.0047569,33.1504589/54.9015883,33.0666052/@54.8215897,32.8193826,10z/data=!4m4!4m3!1m0!1m0!3e0?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The slope of the line joining the two points is $tan \theta$, and it is given by $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the start and end points of the line segment. Can you find $\theta$ from here?

Comment: I have try it but it doesn't work